# How to execute DDL SQL Scripts on Azure Managed instance using Azure portal CLI

Tags: sql-server, azure, mi

I can do all the activities around the frame work of Azure managed Instances like create MI, update, delete tasks and as well I can also take a backup and restore, but how to connect to Azure MI using Azure CLI on portal and execute DDL scripts  like select  * from db.schema.table.

I am getting the error :-

> Connection failed. Error: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

can anyone let me know how to connect  to Azure MI for DDL  operations using Azure CLI on  portal.

once this is successful I want to use same scripts in azure devops pipelines.

Request help.

I have tried these type of commands to make a connection and execute SQL scripts

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
```

And also using `invoke-SQLCMD`

but no luck

Comment: Are you using `az sql db show-connection-string` to generate your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection failed. Error: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"
```

When the SQL server is not configured to allow remote connections, the error may be raised. To configure it, go to the managed instance **networking** tab, enable Public endpoint, and use that endpoint as shown below:

[image]

This option requires port 3342 to be open for inbound traffic. You will need to [configure](https://aka.ms/mimanage-publicendpoint-openport) an NSG rule for this port separately. Go to the subnet of the VNet and select NSG, go to inbound security rules and **Add** a rule that has higher priority than the **deny_all_inbound** rule as shown below:

[image]

Then you will be able to connect the SQL managed instance successfully through Azure CLI using the command below:

```
sqlcmd -S tcp:<serverName>.database.windows.net,3342 -U <userName> -P '<password>' -d db -Q "<query>"
```

[image]

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection#a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server-verify-that-the-instance-name-is-correct-and-that-sql-server-is-configured-to-allow-remote-connections).

Comment: Hi Bhavani,

Thanks for the suggestion, yes that is true and works for my dev environment, I figured this earlier. But all production managed instances are enabled with private endpoints, How to and what to configure if  Azure MI is enabled with private endpoints, Appreciate any help.

Comment: Connect to an Azure SQL Managed Instance with private endpoint enabled using Azure CLI by obtaining the private IP address and configuring network connectivity, then use the sqlcmd command for connection, ensuring proper security and network configurations.

Comment: Thank you, but that is where I need help. 
I assume Azure CLI and Azure devops  makes the connection attempt as from internet, Am I right? So, when MI's are enabled with PE, they block any connections from the internet. I understand and am aware that with in vnet there will be no  problem for connecting to the MI. we have various ways for different connection scenarios.
V-net to Vnet - peering is needed
On premises to azure Vnet - Site to site or express route is needed
Laptop/work station - point to site need to be configured.
but for devops and CLI which are from internet - what we need

Comment: Sorry was out of word limits in my earlier comments.
 what need to be done for the internet connection comiing from internal domain.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: can you check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/public-endpoint-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#confirm-that-routing-is-properly-configured) once?